# Apache: Enable HostnameLookups for single virtual host

Tags: apache2

I have several virtual hosts configured in Apache. Reverse DNS lookups are disabled in apache2.conf with `HostnameLookups Off` but I want it enabled for a single virtual host. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK this directive is in core module so you can't change it only for one host. But you can check the utility [logresolve](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/logresolve.html) and use it to specific log (when you have log rotated or when you want to inspect some requests).